# Error when passing in nil value on Rails object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an app where a user has a portfolio. A portfolio can have many positions and each position can have many movements.

My portfolio show page is built like this:

```
<p>
  <strong>Name:</strong>
  <%= @portfolio.name %>
</p>

<h1>Positions</h1>
<div class = 'table'>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>Stock</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
<tbody id = "positions">
  <%= render @positions %>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>

<h3>New Position</h3>

<%= render 'positions/form' %>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_portfolio_path(@portfolio) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', portfolios_path %>
```

My position partial is built:

```
<tr>
  <td class="col-md-1"><%= position.name %></td>
  <td class="col-md-1"><%= position.quantity %></td>
  <td class="col-md-1"><%= position.ticker %></td>
  <td>
    <%= form_for [@portfolio, position, @movement] do |f| %>
    <div id = "movement-errors">
      <% if @movement.errors.any? %>
        <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: @movement %>
      <% end %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :quantity %>
      <%= f.number_field :quantity, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
       <%= f.submit class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
     </div>
    <% end %>
  </td>
</tr>
```

And my shared errors partial is:

```
<% if object.errors.any? %>
  <div id = "error_explanation">
    <div class = "alert alert-danger">
      The form contains <%= pluralize(object.errors.count, "error") %>.
    </div>
    <ul>
      <% object.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

When I submit a nil value on a movement form, I want the errors to pop up and tell the user the message. I have validations checking for presence of quantity.

```
class Movement < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :position
  validates :quantity, presence: true
```

And my controller movements#create action looks like

```
class MovementsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :load_portfolio_and_position 

def create
  @movement = Movement.new(movement_params)
  @movement.position_id = @position.id
  @movement.update_price
  @movement.date = DateTime.now
  @movement.trade ='buy'

  respond_to do |format|
    if @movement.save
      @position.update_attribute(:quantity, (@movement.quantity + @position.quantity))
      format.html { redirect_to @portfolio, notice: 'Movement was successfully created.' }
    format.js
    else
      format.html { render template: 'portfolios/show' }
      format.json { render json: @movement.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

As it stands right now, when I submit an empty form, I get this error using the better_errors gem:

'nil' is not an ActiveModel-compatible object. It must implement :to_partial_path.

And the render @positions line is highlighted from my portfolio show page. I thought I was implementing a partial path. Is my syntax wrong?

Comment: Maybe I'm being blind but I don't see where you are setting @portfolio in your controller.

Comment: I edited to show my Movement controller before_action. I'm grabbing the portfolio and position objects before all the actions.

Comment: Are you grabbing the `@positions` object in `load_portfolio_and_position ` method?

Comment: does sound like you haven't assigned `@positions` - and the naming of your before_action implies you are setting `@portfolio` and `@position` - not `@positions`. Even if you are assigning them, check that they aren't being assigned nil.

Comment: You can put a nil check in there and if the variable is null, set it to an empty model instance of the correct type.

Answer (score 0):

When passing an object, needs to be assigned like this.

`<%= render partial: 'shared/error_messages', locals: {object: @movement} %>`

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#passing-local-variables

Answer (score 0):

When you pass an object to a partial using the object: attribute, then the partial references that object by the name of the partial

e.g.

When you call

```
<%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: @movement %>
```

the shared/error_messages partial will have a local variable `error_messages` that references `@movement`

When I am only passing one object to a partial I like to use 'as'

e.g.

```
<%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: @movement , as: :movement %>
```

That lets you specify the name of the local variable. If I'm passing multiple objects, I'd use the method @7urkm3n described.